# Query to find emails that have been moved/deleted in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook-2010, microsoft-office-365

I have a user that accidentally (bad swipe or something...she's not sure how it happened) moved a number of emails from the Inbox into the Trash in Outlook.  If she goes into the Trash she can see them, so she can 1 by 1 move them back to the Inbox.  BUT - there were some older emails in the Inbox and she's not 100% sure what they all were, so going back and manually restoring them all will be a time-consuming and difficult process, if not actually impossible.  (Yes, the filing system is obviously not best practices, but we can work on that once we get her email back.)

Note these have not been hard deleted, so we're not talking about recovering deleted items as such.  Is there anywhere in the portal (we're on Office 365), or a query I can run in Powershell to, say, get the subject lines of all items moved into the Trash in the last 24 hours?

Comment: Are you using Outlook as the email client? If so, you can perform an advanced find in the Deleted Items folder to find all items modified in a range that should work for you (today, yesterday, on or before, on or after, etc., etc.).

Comment: *Facepalm*  You're exactly correct.  It's not a 100% match, of course, but it's more than close enough for these purposes.  I was so busy thinking server side I didn't even think client side.  I'll blame the very long day and lack of sleep...;-)  Anyway thank you thank you thank you!  Still curious as to whether there's a way to do this server side, but the current crisis is averted.  If you put it as an answer I'll happily upvote.

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Outlook as the email client? If so, you can perform an advanced find in the Deleted Items folder to find all items modified in a range that should work for you (today, yesterday, on or before, on or after, etc., etc.).